# Best way to storage data in Hybrid app in IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, local-storage

I need to known how to store data in ionic hybrid app, but diference to localstore.

Also, it would be possible to use it with Iphone or Android app.

Comment: btw, you can look at this: http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-lokijs-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We currently use [PouchDB](http://www.pouchdb.org) in one of our app. It can use localstore, SQLite or memory as a backend. Works with iOS and Android. It has an Angular wrapper (separate module), so integrating it into Ionic is a breeze. You can fire up a CouchDB on the development machine, enable synchronization and see what is inside the DB. It also has great plug-ins, e.g. for extensive search queries.

We store a large amount of data in this database and use SQLite. It is not fast, especially on Android. We haven't investigated the performance bottleneck extensively, it might be because of the native-to-JavaScript conversion required by SQLite.

For our next project we will evaluate [LokiJS](http://lokijs.org/). It has less features but it is supposedly faster.

Comment: You can avoid using the SQLite Plugin on Android. Android doesn't have the same size limitations as iOS, and it's slower than both IndexedDB and WebSQL, so there's really no reason to use it.

Comment: Loky js ,  apparently it looks great, this really interests me.

Comment: hi @AMlisasin i'm trying install lokyJs using bower: bower install lokijs --save . but it threw me a error: Git is no installed or not in the PATH. Could you help me.

Comment: You need git to use bower on Windows. Follow the guide at https://github.com/bower/bower to install Git as it is required by bower.

Comment: I have trying to work with loki but i didn't find a concrete sample. Have a simple sample to make me start with it.